# How can I end a meeting series in apple calendar without deleting the past instances?

Tags: calendar

so I made a weekly meeting series in apple calendar which has now come to an end. For "historical" purposes I would like to keep the past meetings in the calendar. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just select the first one to be deleted & press Delete or Backspace.

It will pop up a dialog with choices…

[image]

Click 'Delete All Future Events" - those before the chosen date will remain. e.g in this example the one highlighted in solid green will be the first to be deleted, plus all in future.
It actually never offers to delete events before that date. If you wanted to delete all, you'd have to go back & find the first ever event, then you are offered 'All' as an option.

[image]